# How to get image name of selected UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Hi I have a UIImagePicker and I choose an image. Now I need to get the name of the image that selected from UIImagePicker. Please help me.

Comment: cehk once the duplicate answer , if you not get the answer reply here I reopen the question

Comment: i have seen the solution that is by using ALAssetsLibrary, but it shows that some of the functions are deprecated in iOS 9 and later.

Comment: then update the depcreate method then surely works